# AS3: subtraction not exact

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, subtraction

i made an array stocking simple values (1,1,2,1...) that represent tiles for a small 2D game.

i want to stock a rotation (and extra) parameters in this array, so i added decimals to my values :
1.45, 1.90, 2.0, 1.90...
for example, 1.45 means that i want a grass tile (1), rotated by 45°.

to "parse" my decimals, i do:

```
arr[0] = 2.9;
rot = arr[0] - Math.floor(arr[0]);
```

i should get **0.9**, but i get **0.89999** instead.

Any idea why this easy subtraction in AS3 is not correct? Or maybe should i create another array stocking these "extra" parameters?

Thanks for your lights

Answer (score 3):

This is an inherent problem of [floating point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). You could [round the number](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toFixed%28%29) to a given number of decimal places using `rot = rot.toFixed(2)`, or you could just ignore the tiny differences- it would take a lot for them to add up significantly.

As an aside, you can use `rot = arr[0] % 1` to get the portion after the decimal.

Storing rotation values using decimals doesn't seem optimal, especially since your way only allows rotation up to 100 degrees. Plus, what if you want to store more values than tile type and rotation? Using multiple arrays (or even an array of objects of a custom class) might be best.

Comment: You could also create a custom class, "Tile", which has a "Rotation" property, and subclasses of grass, stone, pavement, carpet, etc.

Comment: May I suggest that in addition to linking to docs, you actually add an example of `toFixed` as well? If the docs were to go down or move, then this answer would no longer be an answer.

Comment: Classes could be a good idea, @CarlF, but I'm not so sure if a subclass for every tile type is the right approach. That might be a lot of unnecessary overhead, depending on how the game works.

Comment: @CheeseWarlock, also you could make a class "Tile" with a property of "texture", where texture can be grass, carpet, etc. Now I'm trying to figure out how a tiling system works when each tile can be individually rotated. Sounds like a very difficult tesselation problem ...

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript uses floating point.   Many decimal fractions are not exactly representable.

You could use another array to deal with the extra parameters, or multiply your values by some static value... like 1,000 ?   this would move the extra params unto whole units.  1000 lets you put any 0-359° value in place.  Although you'll have to do the extra parsing to evaluate a carry from subtraction or addition.

Maybe another array would be best... :)

Answer (score 0):

You're subtracting `Number` objects, which in AS3 are floating point. Floating point numbers inherently have accuracy issues. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems) is an explanation as to why.

Your easiest solution is to round your answer:

```
var arr:Array = [];
arr[0] = 2.9;
var rot:Number = Number(arr[0]) - Math.floor(arr[0]);
var rounded:Number = Number(rot.toFixed(1));
```